# protobuf-net svn repository connection failing

Tags: svn, protobuf-net

Infrequently I download the latest protobuf-net source code from the svn repository. The last time i did so was in september of 2013. Sometime between then and now, it appears that the repository is no longer available and the link from the google code site (http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/checkout) results in an error "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it". Is anyone aware of a new location for the protobuf-net repository or know if Marc Gravell is no longer making it available to the public? Or is it possible I'm doing something wrong and the repository is alive and healthy.

When using tortoise I get this error
Error: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://protobuf-net.googlecode.com/svn/trunk' Error running context: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

When using the command line I get this error
E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://protobuf-net.googlecode.com/svn/trunk'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine here; I suspected there was just a glitch in google's SVN hosting. The code has not been relocated or removed.